# basemap bluemarble plot the opposite longitudinal section

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot a map background using basemap's `bluemarble()` function, in the following manner:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lats=[-25,66]
lons=[60,187]

fig=plt.figure();ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

bmap=Basemap(projection='merc',\
        llcrnrlat=lats[0],llcrnrlon=lons[0],\
        urcrnrlat=lats[1],urcrnrlon=lons[1]-360.,\
        lon_0=(lons[0]+lons[1])/2.,\
        ax=ax)

bmap.bluemarble()
plt.show()
```

I think it is because the domain is crossing the dateline, it gives a map with its x-axis flipped.

If I swap the `llcrnrlon` and `urcrnrlon`:

```
bmap=Basemap(projection='merc',\
        llcrnrlat=lats[0],llcrnrlon=lons[1]-360.,\
        urcrnrlat=lats[1],urcrnrlon=lons[0],\
        lon_0=(lons[0]+lons[1])/2.,\
        ax=ax)
```

the map shows correct orientation, but the wrong domain. I wanted to show the Indian ocean, Euro-asia and west Pacific, however the map shows the remaining longitudes, covering the central-east Pacific, America continents and Atlantic. The `lon_0` argument doesn't seem to do anything.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plot 2 maps joining at dateline:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lats1=[-25, 66]
lons1=[60, 179.95]

fig=plt.figure()
#fig.set_size_inches((7.5, 6))
fig.set_size_inches((10, 9))

ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)


bmap=Basemap(projection='merc',\
        llcrnrlat=lats1[0], llcrnrlon=lons1[0],\
        urcrnrlat=lats1[1], urcrnrlon=lons1[1],\
        lon_0=(lons1[0]+lons1[1])/2.,\
        ax=ax1)

bmap.bluemarble(ax = ax1)

ax1.set_position([0, 0, 0.8, 1])

lats2=[-25,66]
lons2=[-179.95, -150]
bmap=Basemap(projection='merc',\
        llcrnrlat=lats2[0], llcrnrlon=lons2[0],\
        urcrnrlat=lats2[1], urcrnrlon=lons2[1],\
        lon_0=(lons2[0]+lons2[1])/2.,\
        ax=ax2)

bmap.bluemarble(ax = ax2)
ax2.set_position([0.8, 0, 0.2, 1])

ax1.set_aspect('auto')
ax2.set_aspect('auto')

ax1.set_adjustable('datalim')
ax2.set_adjustable('datalim')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. That's clever idea. Better still, adding 'ax1.axis('off'); ax2.axis('off')` removes that vertical line at dateline.